# How to use a perl module?

Tags: perl

I have installed PAR from CPAN. Now, how do you use it? It gives usage example as:

% pp -o hello hello.pl

How do you use this on Windows? pp gives "command not found".

I am new to perl. Only thing I need is to run a module.

Comment: What do you mean by "run a module"?  Be more explicit.  It doesn't sound like you need PAR at all?

Comment: PAR is a module to convert a perl script into exe. But I have no idea how to use it in Windows.

Comment: This is wrong. PAR merely *runs* par-packed archives. [PAR::Packer](http://p3rl.org/PAR::Packer) is the one which *creates* executables and par-packed archives, and also contains the [pp](http://p3rl.org/pp) command-line tool.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should look in your lib directory to ensure that the pp.pm file exists somewhere.  then, you can load it up by typing `use Par::pp;` at the perl command line (i'm guessing that it is part of PAR based on what i've found, it could be something as simple as `use pp;` at the command line).

once the module is loaded, it should provide the pp command for you to use.

thanks,
mark

Comment: Dear Mark, I got it. Your answer helped a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

pp isn't a module, it is an application. You need to figure out where it was installed to (I don't know which perl you are using or how you installed it) and use the full path to it.

Comment: I also looked for that. There is no executable "pp.exe" or whatever.

Comment: OK I got it. You are right. It is "pp.bat" and located under sites/bin/pp.bat